# php: (newbie) database field definition into array

Tags: php, arrays, database-schema

i'd like to write a function which grabs all fields from a database table and puts it in an array.
getting the database fields already works like this:

```
$sq = "select column_name,data_type from information_schema.columns 
where table_name='users'";
```

i'm just not sure how to store them properly.

when having eg. this database structure:

```
fieldname    type      length
--------------------------------
id           int       11
username     varchar   50
pass         varchar   50
lastlogin    date
```

what's the best way to store this data in php in order querying it like this:

```
$field = myFields["username"]; 
echo $field->id."/".$field->type."/".field->length;
```

as you can see i'd like to access the data directly by field name

Comment: Confusing question.  Is the *database structure* you've posted actually the column definitions, i.e. do you have four columns named id, username, pass and lastlogin, or do you have three columns named users, type and length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you connect to the database first. Then do:

```
    $r = mysql_query('SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS fieldname,
                            DATA_TYPE AS type,
                            CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS length
                    FROM information_schema.columns
                    WHERE table_name =  "users" AND column_name = "username"');

if ($r)
{
   $field = mysql_fetch_object($r);

  // $field->type, $field->length, etc.
}
```

Comment: Your answer will only result the first row?

Comment: i've updated my question - i'm talking about database fields and the database information_schema - thx

Comment: @Fuxi Ah I see. I've updated my answer, should do what your looking for. :)

Comment: @Nick yes, since we're returning information about a field in a table, not lots of records.

Comment: @Gary, you still need to loop through all of the columns.  With your current code you're now only going to return the left-most column information?  Forgive me if I'm wrong, I haven't tested your code.

Comment: @Nick, no -- mysql_fetch_object NEVER retuns just "columns" it will return one row/record. One row of data is all that's needed -- this query will return the data about that table field (one record) so no need for a loop. I've tested the code and it works.

Comment: @Gary: apologies, I thought the answer was doing something along the lines of `DESCRIBE <TABLE>` which returns each field specification in a different row.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "YOUR QUERY HERE";
$res = mysql_query($sql);

while ($rowobj = mysql_fetch_object($res)) {
  // do what you want to do with $rowobj
  echo $rowobj->column_name1 . "<br />\n";
  echo $rowobj->column_name2 . "<br />\n";
  // ...rest of code...
  }
```

Put your query into $sql variable and replace column_nameX in while loop with columns you SELECTed with your query.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");

$result = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $username = $row['username'];

    unset($row['username']);

    $result[$username] = (object)$row;
}
```

Then you can access it by using:

```
$result['username']->id
```